# Abstracting multi module architecture with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, multi-module

Lets say I have a `ModuleA-impl` and a `ModuleA-api` and then I have a `DomainModule` that needs data from `ModuleA`. I want the DomainModule to depend on the api and not the impl itself. The problem is obviously because `ModuleA-impl` depends on `ModuleA-api`, `ModuleA-api` cannot see anything `ModuleA-impl` provides, consequently the `DomainModule` cannot see it either.

My goal is if I make a change to `ModuleA-impl` I only want the corresponding API to be rebuilt and not any other modules

I am trying to solve this problem by adding an empty interface in `ModuleA-api` in which the `ModuleA-impl`'s component can implement. and then use this interface to connect everything.

[image]